# How to properly write "\" character

Tags: java

I'm looking for correct way to type "\" character so I don't get "Illegal escape Character" error

Good day, recently I started with Java, taking  online basic course and during one of my practice codes I realized that what my keyboard types as "\" isn't actual the correct escape character and thus my code runs "illegal escape character in string literal" error. Any advice how to type it correctly or how to replace the character in system with the correct one?
This is the code as with the incorrect characer:

```
public class WellFormed {
public static void main(String[] arga) {
    System.out.println("A well-formed Java program has");
    System.out.println("a main method with \{ and \}");
    System.out.println("braces.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A System.out.println statement");
    System.out.println("has \( and \) and usually a");
    System.out.println("String that starts and ends");
    System.out.println("with a \" character");
    System.out.println("\(but we type \\" instead!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `"\\"` instead of `"\"`. Since `\` is an escape character, you need a second one to explicitly tell you want the character `\` literally, and not just escape.

Comment: I need the text to say "(", I was under impresion I need to type \ before the braces as to not mess with the code.

Edit: I tried it withoout the \ in front of "( )" and it work fine, if it would not be a bother, can you please tell which characters require escape character in front of them in text strings?

Comment: @RomanKovarovic since `\ ` is the String escape character in Java, that is the only character that needs it. Other special literals also require it, such as double quote (`\" ` (You don't want it to be interpreted as the end of the string!)), new line (`\n`), carriage return (`\r`), and many others https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 1):

It gives the Illegal Scape Character because '(' and '{' don't have to be escaped.

```
    System.out.println("A well-formed Java program has");
    System.out.println("a main method with { and }");
    System.out.println("braces.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A System.out.println statement");
    System.out.println("has ( and ) and usually a");
    System.out.println("String that starts and ends");
    System.out.println("with a \" character");
    System.out.println("(but we type \\\" instead!");
```

The code above compiles and works as expected.

The characters that can be used as an escape sequence are:

```
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

You can find the documentation for Java 8 here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class WellFormed {
public static void main(String[] arga) {
    System.out.println("A well-formed Java program has");
    System.out.println("a main method with \\{ and \\}");
    System.out.println("braces.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A System.out.println statement");
    System.out.println("has \\( and \\) and usually a");
    System.out.println("String that starts and ends");
    System.out.println("with a \" character");
    System.out.println("(but we type \\\" instead!");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are discouraged, you should explain the code, and what it does as well as provide some context to help the OP understand your answer better